# How can I find out whether Win10 was newly installed or upgraded from Win7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, upgrade

I want to find out whether my windows 10 is newly installed or it is upgraded from win7. Is there any mechanism or any way to find out this problem? If it has a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup`
- If you see an `Upgrade` key/folder under this location, then the system
  underwent an upgrade from an older version of Windows
- To see the *old* Windows build number, look at the value of
  `DownlevelBuildNumber`. A value of `6.1.7601` means the system upgraded
  from Windows 7 (a value of `10.0.#####` means it upgraded from some
  build of Windows 10)
- If the `Upgrade` key/folder does not exist, then the system has a clean
  Windows installation

Answer (score -1):

Well. Its a bit tricky to find out.

You can find the installation date of your Windows 10 using the below command,

```
systeminfo | find /i "install date"
```

However, if you had upgraded your Windows from a lower to a higher version, you'll only see the date when the earlier version was installed and not when the latest version was installed or upgraded.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David R for your solution
We'll get installation date of earlier version, but how can we find current version installed date?
If I get this query then I can compare between earlier and current dates and then we can conclude my current windows is newly installed or upgraded from lower version.